# 0403-057 Syntax error at line 21 : `fi' is not expected

Tags: shell, aix, hp-ux

I can't find the root cause of this script's error.
Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.
Here is the whole script detail.

```
#!/bin/sh

CWD=`pwd`
LAUNCH_DIRECTORY=`eval dirname $0`
cd $LAUNCH_DIRECTORY
LAUNCH_DIRECTORY=`pwd`
cd $CWD

if [ -d "${LAUNCH_DIRECTORY}/java/bin" ]; then
  JAVA_HOME=${LAUNCH_DIRECTORY}/java
fi

if [ "${JAVA_HOME}" != "" ]; then
  PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
fi

JAVA_VERSION=$(java -version 2>&1 | grep -i version | \
               cut -d'"' -f2 | cut -         d'.' -f2)

if [ -z "${JAVA_VERSION}" ] || [ "${JAVA_VERSION}" -lt 8 ]; then
  YAB_JAVA_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=256m ${YAB_JAVA_OPTS}"
fi

export TERM=xterm

java ${YAB_JAVA_OPTS} \
     -Dlaunch.dir="${LAUNCH_DIRECTORY}" \
     -jar "${LAUNCH_DIRECTORY}/lib/yab-loader.jar" ${YAB_OPTS} ${1+"$@"}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not indicate that you invested time & effort to solve the problem yourself. What did you try so far? Delta-debugging, for example?

Comment: Replace `cut -         d'.' -f2` with `cut -d'.' -f2` (remove tab or spaces before the `d`)

Answer (score 0):

```
 if [ -z "${JAVA_VERSION}" ] || [ "${JAVA_VERSION}" -lt 8 ]; then
```

is not correct. Replace - for instance - by

```
if [ "${JAVA_VERSION:-0}" -lt 8 ]; then
```

Other possibility:

```
 if ( [ -z "${JAVA_VERSION}" ] || [ "${JAVA_VERSION}" -lt 8 ] ); then
```

Or like this:

```
 if [ -z "${JAVA_VERSION}" -o "${JAVA_VERSION}" -lt 8 ]; then
```

Or this:

```
 [ -z "${JAVA_VERSION}" ] || [ "${JAVA_VERSION}" -lt 8 ] && YAB_JAVA_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=256m ${YAB_JAVA_OPTS}"
```

Reason: The "argument" to `if` must be a command. What you wrote, were two commands connected by `||`.

Aside from this, a closing parenthisis is missing in the assignment of the variable `JAVA_VERSION`.

Comment: Follow your comments:
`if [ "${JAVA_VERSION:-0} -lt 8 ]; then`
result >>> 0403-057 Syntax error at line 44 : `"' is not matched.

`if ( [ -z "${JAVA_VERSION}" ] || [ "${JAVA_VERSION}" -lt 8 ] ); then`
result >>> 0403-057 Syntax error at line 41 : `fi' is not expected.

`if [ -z "${JAVA_VERSION}" -o "${JAVA_VERSION}" -lt 8 ]; then`
result >>> -XX:MaxPermSize=256m :  not found.
           0403-057 Syntax error at line 41 : `fi' is not expected.

Comment: The line where you set JAVA_VERSION is missing a closed parenthesis.

Comment: @user1934428 : Please add the missing quote in your answer, the line `if [ "${JAVA_VERSION:-0} -lt 8 ]; then`.